# ExtendedProperty is not available in the get event api response

Tags: google-calendar-api

We are working on Google Calendar Add-on and need some help regarding Add-on development. 
• We used to set the key-value pair under “ExtendedProperty -> private” section of the event and read it on need basis. Earlier(a week back) “ExtendedProperty->private” used to be available but now, we are seeing that “ExtendedProperty” itself is not available in the event response. Whenever we are trying to fetch the key from the event response, error with message “Cannot read property "private" from undefined” occurred.

• Sample event response when extended property was available:

````
   ```{  
     "kind":"calendar#event",
     "etag":"\"3109778738149000\"",
     "id":"5s2qqbjgqghjo5611mndeb9p17",
     "status":"confirmed",
     "extendedProperties":{  
        "private":{  
           "everyoneDeclinedDismissed":"-1",
           "Recurence":"Single"
        }
     },
     "conferenceData":{ },
     "reminders":{ }
  }```
````

• Sample event response when extended property is not available: 
       `{

         "kind":"calendar#event",
         "etag":"\"3132407561772000\"",
         "id":"6o22abo31tj8f75j3tsueg5k5c",
         "status":"confirmed,
         "conferenceData":{ },
         "reminders":{ }
       }`

• Sample code for reading/writing into the event response.

````
  o Get:  ```{Event_Response}.extendedProperties.private.Recurence
  o Set:   
    {Event_Response}.extendedProperties.private['Recurence'] = value
    Calendar.Events.patch(Event_Response, accountId, eventid)```
````

• Is there any change at API level occurred because get and set for the extended property was working properly earlier(a week back).